# Using Tietze’s Extension Theorem if the function is not real-valued

Tags: general-topology

I came across this problem while reading about Tietze’s Extension Theorem in my professor’s old lecture notes:

- “Suppose X is $T_4$, A$\subseteq$X is closed, and $f:A \rightarrow D$ is continuous, where $D= {\{(x,y) \in \mathbb(R)^2 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 }\}$ is the closed unit disk in $\mathbb(R)^2$. Show that there is a continuous $F: X \rightarrow D$ such that the restriction of $F$ to A is $f$.”

My first thought was that this looks like something I need to use Tietze’s extension theorem on, but the issue is that it’s not a real valued function. I know how to handle the case when the co-domain is the unit circle and the range of f is closed (namely there exists an open arc in the unit circle a such that the range is contained in the unit circle minus the arc, a closed arc so it is homeomorphic to [0,1], from there use Tietze’s extension theorem) but in this case I’m at a loss. We don’t know that the range of A is closed in D and I can’t think of some sort of analogous argument to the arc one used above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalisation of Tietze Extension Theorem for Compact Hausdorff Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756107) Even when the codomain is the unit circle, your idea doesn't work if the range of $f$ is the whole circle.

Comment: But (contrarily to the circle) $D$ is fine (as explained in the duplicate) because it is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2,$ to which Tietze applies componentwise.

Comment: Yes, that very much answers my question, thank you so much!